# Excel vba Application.CalculateFull only on defined range

Tags: vba, excel

Im using code in this link to get exchangerates from yahoo:
https://desmondoshiwambo.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/how-to-get-the-current-exchange-rateconvert-currency-in-access-excel-and-vba-using-yahoo-finance/

And this works great. My only challenge now is to update exchangerates without using Application.CalculateFull. Since i only need the range (A2:D6) to refresh.

I have tried with .calculate but that does not refresh the data. Only entering into the formula and push enter, and also calculatefull works.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I cant open the link, so not sure of the method, can it be done via linking the webpage in data --> from web, then you can refresh the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
 'Application.CalculateFull
 With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sh1").Range("A2:D6") ' change this line as you need
  .Formula = .Formula
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked :) But it didnt help. Seems like the function on itself is what takes time running.. But thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @OyvPet, You are welcome, and yes you are right, I notice that but I think it is normal to be slow because the UDF use internet connection.